# How to track changes on IBM Portal 6.0 made by multiple users accessing Portal admin console

Tags: admin, portal

The context of this question is to be able to **control** changes made by multiple users with **Portal administration rights** on a **development** environment, such that we can share the accountabilty and be able to track **who** made **what** changes **when**

With that in mind is there a way to enable **audit trail** in **IBM Portal 6.0** and if **yes** how ?

Also, if **yes** is that feature available to view by **all** administrators ?

I am assuming that there is a way that multiple user's can be granted **admin rights** on the **IBM Portal admin console**

I know it is a **bad** idea to have multiple user's / developers sharing and making changes to the portal with admin rights on the same **environment** however if such a situation does arise how does one deal with it, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

@user2257853, there is no way in Portal 6.0

However, you can add database triggers to track the changes made by the users.  it'd be hand crafted